# How to make a checkbox query with multiple statements?

Tags: php, mysql

my mysql and php skills are limited.
I have a database with songs, with a genre column.
I´m trying to make a query using checkbox, using the post below:

the HTML

```
 <html>
 <span><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="1">Rock</span>
 <span><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="2">Jazz</span>... (other 10 genres)

  <?php
  $genre = implode(' or ', (array)$_POST['check_list'.$i]);
  ?>   
  </html>
```

The PHP gets:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from songs where genre_id='$genre' ORDER BY RAND() limit 10")
```

The result are 10 randomics songs (from both select genres). What i need is 10 for each checked genre (20 songs, 10 each). Is that possible?

EDIT:
and results should be (if rock and jazz selected), first 10 rock then 10 jazz, not mixed.

Thx

Comment: One way to achieve this is by re-arranging the answer you getting from query return using Php. Another way can be running the query inside a for each loop which is not sure wise and recommended.

Answer (score -1):

please use below code

```
  $genre = implode(' , ', (array)$_POST['check_list'.$i]);
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from songs where genre_id IN ($genre) ORDER BY RAND() limit 10")
```

Comment: Still printing 10 mixed results.